# Como deixar um preço variavel em javascript aparecer como negrito no site

Tags: javascript

Tenho um codigo em js que divide o valor do produto em 12x porém gostaria que esse valor junto com o R$ apareça em negrito.

Aqui o codigo

```
productPrices.innerHTML+= "<br>";
productPrices.innerHTML+='<p style="color: #black; font-size:17px;margin-bottom:6px;top: 6px;position: relative">em até <b>12x</b> de '.concat(Currency.formatMoney(newVariant.price/12*1.2161,window.theme.moneyFormat),"</p>")
```

No site ele aparece assim:

[Preço parcelado em 12x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nterv.png)

Answer (score -1):

Eu faria o seguinte...
Dividiria o que eu quero em uma TAG tipo STRONG,  com uma class própria e faria a estilização no css. Toda vez que solicitado, a TAG passa a existir para o navegador e o css agirá sobre ela.

`<strong class:"price">12xprice</strong>`

Comment: obrigado pela resposta amigo mas eu não conheço praticamente nada de programação nem html ou  css sei o basico do basico, como examente eu faria isso funcionar naquele codigo

Comment: Desculpe a demora, pq acabei de chegar do trabalho.
tente substituir por este.
´´´productPrices.innerHTML+= "<br>";
productPrices.innerHTML+='<p style="color: #black; font-size:17px;margin-bottom:6px;font-weight: bold;top: 6px;position: relative">em até <b>12x</b> de '.concat(Currency.formatMoney(newVariant.price/12*1.2161,window.theme.moneyFormat),"</p>")´´´

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, com o seu código fica todo o texto em negrito eu preciso que apenas o valor final fique em negrito R$ 12,96